# WordPress: All links redirect to Home page, but only on HTTPS links

Tags: wordpress

I’m running a WordPress website and have run into a puzzling issue. Every link in my Menu opens the Home page instead and the intended page won’t open.

Now, what is weird is that this is only happening with links that point at HTTPS. If I embed HTTP links on the page instead, then the pages open just fine.

I’ve disabled all Plugins and it is still happening.

The host is Go Daddy. Could they have messed up our SSL certificate settings?

Anyone run into this before and solved it?

Site in question is: https://earthancients.com

Comment: The links work fine. If you see the URL, they all change correctly.

The problem then lies in all your URLs leading to the same place.

Comment: Yes, I take your point. So why is that happening and why only with the HTTPS links?

Comment: I can't check the HTTP version because i'm automatically redirected to HTTPS, it may be my browser doing it. I don't think the problem lays in HTTP tho, it's probably something else.

Answer (score 0):

I manually switch HTTPS to HTTP, seems to have the same problem? Can you check the page Permalink in the background Post? Maybe there's something wrong here?
***Admin--Pages--All Pages--Home***
There is a Permalink label on the right to view

Comment: Thanks for looking. That looks all fine to me, when I go into the Page to edit it shows:

Permalink: https://www.earthancients.com/

So, I don't think that is the problem?